# extjs takes 30 secs to load

Tags: ajax, extjs, compression

Extjs takes 30 secs to load. Is there a way to compress the fle

Comment: There's a compressed version, and hosting as @Joe says. But have you actually confirmed it's ExtJS that's causing the delay?

Comment: Make sure you use `ext-all.js` not `ext-all-debug.js`.

Comment: The size of the file is not the problem. There's something else going on.

Comment: I'm surprised anyone's even bothered to answer.  You have asked 13 questions and haven't accepted a single answer.  Your question gets my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Hosting to speed up the downloading of ExtJS: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

For example, you would use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"></script>
```

Instead of linking to your own website,

Comment: you think its a speed issue on my server or google has a very compressed version

Comment: Of course that is only ext core. I don't know of a CDN hosting the full library.